# Can I create an MSI with WiX that upgrades an application installed using a Burn Bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, wix3.7, burn

Say I have an application that has been installed using a Setup.exe created by a WiX Bootstrapper project.  I now have a new version of the application I wish users to upgrade to, but for various reasons, I would like to distribute this upgrade as an MSI, not a .exe.

When I tested this, I found that I ended up with 2 instances of the application showing up in Add/Remove Programs, one the version installed by the .exe and one by the .msi.

I note that both the Product element in the Setup project and the Bundle in the Bootstrapper project both have UpgradeCode attributes which differ.  I did attempt to create an MSI with the same UpgradeCode as the Bundle to test, but this displayed the same behaviour as before.

Is there a way to upgrade a Setup.exe installed product with an MSI?

Comment: The problem with this is that a bundle is not the same as an MSI. They are not registered with Windows Installer and they don't necessarily need to appear in ARP. Is there a concrete reason why you don't just have your bundle install this one MSI?

Comment: Did you finally solve this? I am stuck with the exact same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Create the new MSI with the same upgrade code as the MSI which you installed using your Bootstrapper. If the MSI upgrade code is same, then it will know that they are related products and do (either uninstall prev version, upgrade etc) based on what you have mentioned in your MSI.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but without success.  I believe it's because the upgrade code being registered with the Windows Installer infrastructure is actually that of the bootstrapper <Bundle> element.

Comment: From what you have written above "I note that both the Product element in the Setup project and the Bundle in the Bootstrapper project both have UpgradeCode attributes which differ."

Comment: I understood that you made the Upgrade of your MSI same as that of the Bundle/bootstrapper. Thats not what I said. What I meant is to make the new MSI upgrade code exactly same as the upgrade of the MSI WITHIN your bundle/bootstrapper (not the bundle/bootstrappers upgrade code). Do you get my point?

Comment: @Isaiah4110 - That still won't get rid of the old bundle. It WILL upgrade the MSI, that is correct, but the old entry from the bundle will still stay in place.

Comment: Check this answer, write a script to remove the bundle entry from the rehgistry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109387/removing-bad-installs-from-add-remove-programs/18109613#18109613