# Wix Major upgrade to InstallShield package leaves entry in Add/Remove programs, despite actually uninstalling

Tags: windows, wix, installation, installshield

I am building an installer package using WiX, which I intend to replace an InstallShield MSI package. As part of the install process, the WiX package uninstalls the old package. The problem, is that it leaves a renegade item in the Add/Remove Programs list. I'm just using the wix 3.5 entry:

`<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. 'Setup will now exit." />`

What's weird is that:

- UpgradeCode GUID is the same for both packages
- Product Id GUID for the new package is new.
- The old package's files and shortcuts and everything actually do get removed.
- Looking at the log file, RemoveExistingProducts actually removes the package.
- Nothing pertaining to the old package lives in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

So I suspect that it is some installshield weirdness that is the cause of all this. While it would be nice to have WiX do everything for me, I am ok with blasting any entries for the old package in the registry or wherever else the ARP dialog looks, if someone can point me to further information on how to do that?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure nothing is here: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`? I believe InstallShield puts two entries in there. One in `Uninstall\[ProductCode]` and the other in something similar to `Uninstall\InstallShield_blahblabh`. I'd check and if you find a reference to the product, manually delete it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109387/removing-bad-installs-from-add-remove-programs/18109613#18109613

Answer (score 0):

The InstallShield package will leave the below key in the registry. You can delete it from the WiX package.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\InstallShield_{[ProductId]}
```

`[ProductId]` is the Id of the InstallShield package beeing upgraded.